# How to prevent duplication when I reload my page to insert csv file to the database in laravel

Tags: laravel, csv, methods, duplicates

Data duplicates in the database when I reload the code using laravel

I have tried to use laravel methods like "updateOrInsert" or "updateOrCreate " to prevent csv data duplication but it does't work? Please help!!

Here is the section how to import csv data to database

```
public function importCsv()
    {    
        $products = $this::parseCsv('data.csv');
        var_dump($products);

        if (!empty($products)) {

            foreach($products as $product) {
                Product::create($product);  
            }
        }

        DB::table('products')
            ->updateOrInsert(
            ['name' => 'Jonathan', 'job'=>'consult'],
            ['name' => 'Johana']
        );

        return $this->parseCsv('data.csv');
    }
```

Csv data duplicates in the database

Comment: I still didn't find the answer for this problem, I'm gonna to be crazy because of it. Please help in any one know how to prevent duplicating when I import CSV file to the database using laravel when I run my code through reloading the web browser

Answer (score 0):

Laravel determines whether the record already exists in the database by attempting to find it using the id of the record, not by comparing the data.

Your CSV file needs to have an id field that matches in both the CSV record and the database record.

Comment: Thanks for your help.But i'm still didn't anderstand. what do you mean by having id field that matches in both the CSV record and DB. As I understood that I must use this method  "updateOrInsert" to update the id in database so can not duplicate the data in DB when I reload the browser "my code who uses to import CSV data to DB" . Please clarify more if you know anything about this function or another one can help me to solv this problem..

Comment: Could you Andy Cowan show me please how can I do this. You said that my csv file needs to have an id field that matches in both csv and database record. Thanks in advance!!!